# How many dots do I have to write?

Tags: soft-question, definition

This seems very odd and silly. But I do not know where else  to ask.

This question occurs to me whenever I write an infinite sequence, sum or decimal points etc.

Ex: $ 1.2 + 2.3 + 3.4 + ……………$

Ex: $1.2345 .....$

How many dots are used to represent that it follows the same pattern endlessly?

Is there a certain number of dots that should be written?

Comment: The same amount that should be written in normal English… three.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis

Comment: Well that's new to me ! Thank you !

Comment: You wont be doing the dots, you will use \cdots tex, latex,mathjax as so $\cdots$

Comment: Also, don't put spaces between your sentences and your exclamation marks!

Comment: Then again, dots are always a bad thing and the opposite of mathematical rigor. Is your second example $1.23455555\ldots$ or $1.234567890123456789012345\ldots$ or $1.23456789101112131415161718192021\ldots$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ex : $1.2 + 2.3 + 3.4 + \dotsb$

MathJax: `$1.2 + 2.3 + 3.4 + \dotsb$` (“dots with binary operators/relations”)

Ex : $1.2345 \dotso$

MathJax: `$1.2345 \dotso$` (“other dots”)

See [Martin's MathJax Guide](http://www.martinkeefe.com/math/mathjax4), 4.6. Dots

Comment: These can also be done by writing `\cdots` and `\dots`, respectively.

Comment: To cite 3.12.: "Note 2. Although the commands
\cdots
and
\ldots
are frequently used, we recommend the more semantically oriented commands
\dotsb
\dotsc
\dotsi
\dotsm
\dotso
for most purposes (see 4.6)."

Comment: That's interesting. I guess it's to make it easier to read if you can't get the LaTeX to render (like, if you're just reading the code).